# Is there a way to create custom fields on Pages or any other type of content from code and having them show on the insert & edit views?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

Currently I have a sitefinity project in which there was the need to create custom fields for pages, custom product types & custom fields on those.

The problem is keeping all this custom fields in synch across different environments, dev, qa, ect.

I've tried the following the documentation regarding this,

https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-create-custom-fields-with-the-api

the problem is the fields do not show in the in the insert/edit view, they only show if the fields were created with the sitefinity backend UI instead of doing it with code.

Answer (score 0):

To add custom fields, go to Pages, and in the right-hand column under "settings for pages" there is a link for "Custom Fields." When you create a custom field here it will show up on the Title and Properties section of the page (the first page you see when you create a page, before you get to the page layout builder). If you do not see this setting, you may be running an outdated version of Sitefinity.